# Live site updating with ajax? JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There was a site 'happybirthdadstevejobs.com' where people wished Steve happy birthday and when you did you were added and the site was being continually updated with other wishing Steve a happy birthday too.

I want to figure this out as I have an idea to teach kids some science concepts. Can anyone help me understand what I need to do?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you want to do? I assume you want to fetch some data using ajax over an interval (e.g. every 10 seconds) where the data may be updated by other users.

Comment: True, what **do you** want to figure out. Please update your question before it closes down.

Comment: @calum @giddy I want students on multiple machines to be updating comments based upon what is on the screen and other comments from others that appear as they are going along. So Person A types "photosynthesis" and submits, Person B sees Photosynthesis updated while they are typing "chlorophyll"

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery

```
var i = setInterval(function() {
   $.getJSON("inc/messages.php?"+ params, function(data) {
      $('#updates').html(data.messages);
   }
}, 1000);
```

So that will get some messages from messages.php and output them to the element with id 'updates' every second.

To stop the updates, you can call:

```
clearInterval(i)
```

However, there is probably a more efficient way to do it if the file is going to be called many times.

Edit: forgot to mention that messages.php needs to grab the data from a database or file :)

Answer (score 0):

Try googling Long Polling.

Node.js is a good option for long polling.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea to even search for that.